# Capcut webgl2 problem

Tags: lubuntu

Hello I tried to run capcut webapp on my Lubuntu laptop but it says the browser is not supported when I check the webgl2 in the browser settings it's enabled so what is the problem

> Lubuntu version is 22.04.4 LTS and this problem is on every browser

Comment: Have you tried installing an extension to fake a Windows user agent?

Comment: @DanielT I haven't but what extension should I use

Comment: @guiverc my Lubuntu version is 22.04.4 LTS and this problem is on every browser I am thinking about installing a windows chrome with wine